# this.value return brackets with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe this could be a stupid question, but I'm not an expert of jQuery, so I need some explanation. I want get the value of the selected option in my select. So I write this code:

```
var actual_option = $(this).find('option:selected', this).map(function ()
{
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

When the user click on my select this variable will valorize through the option value, the problem's that the final result is this:

> ["2"]

instead of this

> 2

How avoid the brackets?

Comment: `get()` returns an array!

Comment: Why are you using map() if you want to get only one value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for `.map()` or `.get()` here. Your returned value has brackets, because `.get()` returns an array.

Considering `$(this)` represents a `<select>`-Tag, you can simply do:

```
var actual_option = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the value is returned in an array is because you're using `map()` - which you don't actually need in this instance.

Assuming `this` refers to the select element itself `$(this).val()` will work:

```
var actual_option = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var actual_option = $(this).find('option:selected', this).map(function ()
{
    return this.value;
}).get(0);
```

Try this

Comment: This working fine, the 0 in the get what does mean? Thank you for this :)

Comment: it should be `...}).get()[0];` to return the first index of the array as i.e. `2`

Answer (score 1):

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) turns the entire collection into a native array. You can specify an index by using `.get(0)`:

```
var actual_option = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function ()
{
    return this.value;
}).get(0);
//     ^
```

but this is excessive, when you could simply call [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to return the value of the first element in the selected collection of elements.

```
var actual_option = $(this).val();
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only takes a single parameter, so `.find('option:selected', this)` should just be `.find('option:selected')`

It looks like you were trying to use the selector shorthand of `$('option:selected', this)` which is equivalent to `$(this).find('option:selected')`.